# #include fail: qmake not including path properly?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, juce

Using Qt, I have the following line in my `.pro` project file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /home/myuser/JUCE/modules/
```

for which the directory contains a bunch of directories like "/juce_audio_basics/"
which contain a header file with the same name as the respective directory.

But in a header file in my project, doing

```
#include <juce_audio_basics/juce_audio_basics.h>
```

gives me a `No such file or directory` error.

Seems like a really basic problem, and I don't see what is messing it up.

What am I missing?

Edit:

Only the top #include of those files throws an error - commenting the first makes the second one return an error (at compile-time). The editor only outlines the first in the list - but even the "Follow symbol under cursor" works bringing me to the correct file within the IDE. How does this make any sense?

Comment: Try to rerun `qmake`.

Comment: @vahancho trust me, I've tried. Many, many times..

Comment: whats the compiler output? you should see "-I /home/myuser/JUCE/modules" when compiling the offending .cpp file. If so, check the compiler has read access to these files (and +x on the directories!). And maybe try to include the file with apostrophes **"** instead of **<>**